# Accessing ntfs in a M.2 SSD containing Windows installation

Tags: windows, ntfs, ntfs-3g

My Linux installation (running from an internal HDD) has no problem accessing ntfs partitions, expect for the new M.2 SSD.

Gparted reports that I need ntfsprogs, but as far as I know its functionality was already included in ntfs-3g, which I have.

From gparted I get 4 partitions:

```
| Name:  | EFI system partition | Microsoft reserved partition | Basic data partition | Basic data partition |
| FS:    | fat32                | unknown                      | ntfs                 | ntfs                 |
| Label: | SYSTEM               |                              | Windows              | WinRe_DRV            |
| Boot:  | boot, hidden esp     | msftres                      | msftdata             | hidden, diag         |
```

I might need to access files that I have used under Windows, therefore I have special interest in mounting the Windows labelled partition.

I was expecting to access the partitions on a M.2 drive in an identical way to that of any other drive.

Some operations are unavailable under gparted since the partition is not readable. I'd like to resize said partition and transfer my Linux installation to the M.2.

Comment: @Fabby: no, they are not dynamic partitions, which have been deprecated a couple of years ago. it's a new installation.

Comment: OK, dumb comment deleted.  **:-)**  What does Windows say then because parted doesn't show anything...